# How to retrieve a single data from SQLite in TextView?

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

At this time I need help from u guys, I have a question how to get a single data from database into `TextView`?

Here is the code from DBDataSource.java

```
package com.example.database.search;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

public class DBDataSource {
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private DBHelper dbHelper;
private String[] allColumns = { DBHelper.COLUMN_ID,
          DBHelper.COLUMN_NAMA_SMA, 
          DBHelper.COLUMN_ALAMAT_SMA, 
          DBHelper.COLUMN_LATITUDE_SMA, 
          DBHelper.COLUMN_LONGTITUDE_SMA,
          DBHelper.COLUMN_TANGGAL_BERDIRI_SMA, 
          DBHelper.COLUMN_EMAIL_SMA, 
          DBHelper.COLUMN_WEBSITE_SMA, 
          DBHelper.COLUMN_FACEBOOK,
          DBHelper.COLUMN_TWITTER };
public DBDataSource(Context context)
{
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
}
private Sma cursorToSma(Cursor cursor)
{

    Sma sekolah = new Sma();
    Log.v("info", "The getLONG "+cursor.getLong(0));
    Log.v("info", "The setLatLng "+cursor.getString(1)+","+cursor.getString(2));

    sekolah.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
    sekolah.setNama(cursor.getString(1));
    sekolah.setAlamat(cursor.getString(2));
    sekolah.setLatitude(cursor.getLong(3));
    sekolah.setLongitude(cursor.getLong(4));
    sekolah.setTgl_berdiri(cursor.getString(5));
    sekolah.setEmail(cursor.getString(6));
    sekolah.setWebsite(cursor.getString(7));
    sekolah.setFacebook(cursor.getString(8));
    sekolah.setTwitter(cursor.getString(9));


    return sekolah;
}

public ArrayList<Sma> getPoint(String name)
{
    ArrayList<Sma> daftarPoint = new ArrayList<Sma>();

    Sma sekolah= new Sma(); //inisialisasi barang
    String query = "select COLUMN_NAMA_SMA, COLUMN_LATITUDE_SMA, COLUMN_LONGTITUDE_SMA    from sma where COLUMN_NAMA_SMA ='" + name + "'";
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery(query, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) 
    {
      sekolah = cursorToSma(c);
      daftarPoint.add(sekolah);
      c.moveToNext();
    }
    c.close();
    return daftarPoint;

}
```

And here the code from `SearchResultActivity`, In this case, I want to call method `getPoint` in this `Activity`, but the method getPoint has an parameter, right? The parameter is parsing with the query. The code is below:

```
package com.example.search;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import com.example.database.search.*;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SearchResultsActivity extends ListActivity {

  private DBDataSource dataSource; 
  private ArrayList<Sma> values;
  private TextView txtQuery;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_result);

        dataSource = new DBDataSource(this);
          // buka kontroller
          dataSource.open();

        // get the action bar
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Enabling Back navigation on Action Bar icon
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        txtQuery = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtQuery);
        handleIntent(getIntent());

 }
 @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) 
 {
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
 }
 /**
     * Handling intent data
     */
 private void handleIntent(Intent intent) 
 { 
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) 
        {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

            //I WANT CALL THE METHOD getPoint right here by parsing the query
                //and I WANT TO SHOW IT IN TEXTVIEW
            /**
             * Use this query to display search results like 
             * 1. Getting the data from SQLite and showing in listview 
             * 2. Making webrequest and displaying the data 
             * For now we just display the query only
             */
            txtQuery.setText("Search Query: " + query);

        }
 }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you need any more help with this question?

Comment: yeah of course, can u help @VonSchnauzer

Comment: We have written quite a lot in our answers. Please give feedback on our solutions, on why they may not work. And please answer the questions as well. If you do that we might help. Answer with an edit to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

this is my code may be it will help u

```
db.open();
            Cursor c = db.getautobackupSettings(session.getUserId());
            if(c.getCount()>0)
            {
                c.moveToPosition(0);
                int camerabackup = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("your colomn name"));


                }
            db.close
```

and its my getautobackupSettings() methos in database which give all data

```
public Cursor getautobackupSettings(int userId)
    {
        return db.rawQuery("select * from autobackupSettings where user_id="+userId, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you want it displayed in a ListView and TextView, I suppose you mean: display data in a TextView in a ListView. But you also say "*display a single data from database*". Which is it? Display list or just one text item?

For displaying a list of items you will have to use an Adapter for displaying your data.

I've just created a rudimentary logic for you. You will have to read up on ListActivities here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html and also any converting to an ArrayList if you want this solution, since this particular ArrayListAdapter takes just that.

If you want a more advanced Adapter, you can find info here: [Custom Adapter for List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)

The code has a lot of comments since the requirements are a bit unclear.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_result);
    txtQuery = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtQuery);
    dataSource = new DBDataSource(this);
    // buka kontroller
    dataSource.open();
    // get the action bar
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    DBDataSource db = new DBDataSource(this);
    //Get that "name" from intent
    String qparam = handleIntent(getIntent());
    ArrayList<Sma> list = db.getPoint(qparam);
    ArrayList<String> convertedList = convert(list); //a method you write, or you simply return an ArrayList<String> from your db.getPoint(String qparam);

    //ArrayAdapter - however, you can use most any adapter if you need more 
    //advanced data. if all you have is a list of strings, this is fine. 

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
             this, 
             android.R.layout.<your text view layout for row>,
             list );

     setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 
    // Enabling Back navigation on Action Bar icon
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //handleIntent(getIntent());

}
```

Change your handleIntent(Intent intent) to

```
 private String handleIntent(Intent intent){

  ...
  return name;
 }
```